# converting html file into pdf using jspdf library

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas

I am trying to convert the html file to pdf using jsPDF library. But in the code I implemented, the whole image is not converting into pdf. Only half of it is visible. Could someone please tell me where am I wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0,0);
context.lineTo(200,100);
context.closePath();
context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
context.stroke();

download.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // only jpeg is supported by jsPDF
 var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",1.0);              
var pdf = new jsPDF();
 pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);

var download = document.getElementById('download');
  pdf.save("download.pdf");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://parall.ax/parallax/js/jspdf.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:solid #0000ff;">
</canvas>
<button id="download">download</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently did some research on converting html to pdfs. I looked at jsPDF, but it seemed better suited for embedding PDF documents into html pages.

If you're looking to export a html page to PDF you may want to consider https://github.com/fraserxu/electron-pdf, which is what I ultimately decided to use.  Electron generates output consistent with the 'print to pdf' feature in Chrome.

Note: this is a server-side rendering solution.  If you have to do it client-side then it is not the right solution.